# Open form in new popup window that is sized

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

I created the new form and the button that pass some parameters to another page; but I need the Submit button to open new pop-up window that is sized to specifications.

this is how I do it via the hyperlink; I need same functionality for the Button

```
out.println("<a onclick=\"window.open(this.href,this.target,'height=500, scrollbars=1, width=950, resizable');return false;\" target=\"_blank\"  href=\"chart.jsp?room=" + B.getNumber() + "&building=" + B.getBuilding() + "\">view chart</a>");
```

Comment: I've added the [tag:javascript] tag, because I don't think this is possible without it and seems almost the most important tag, certainly above [tag:new-window] (which has zero followers), or the [tag:submit] tag (which at least has five).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is without using in-line JavaScript:

```
var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0]; // or any other way to identify the form

form.onsubmit = function(e) {
    var eTarget = e.target;
    window.open(eTarget.action, eTarget.name, 'height=500, scrollbars=1, width=950, resizable');
    return false;
};​
```

[JS Fiddle proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/YGKmg/1/).